# Parse plain text containing articles with headers and text body to Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, text

I am new in coding in Python. I want to convert a factiva text file into a Pandas data frame.

Here is the sample of the factiva text file:

> Section
> US Treas Dept on Feb 13 makes public text of speech made by Sec Shultz at...
>
> 228 words
> 15 February 1974
> New York Times Abstracts
> NYTA
> Pg. 1, Col. 1
> English
> c. 1974 New York Times Company
>
> US Treas Dept on Feb 13 makes public text of speech made by Sec Shultz at closed session of 13-nation energy conf in which he lists ideas and suggestions for dealing with purely financial problems raised for world by huge increase in price of oil. High officials elaborate at background news briefing. Shultz emphasizes that there is no internatl financial arrangement which can offset real effects of oil pricechanges. Adds that there is no way to print money and use it to 'paper over' problem of high price of oil and its impact on employment, prices and real incomes in rich and poor countries. Shultz's ideas were designed to keep real problem from being made worse by huge new money flows involved, amounting to some $50-billion more in '74 than in '73 from oil-consuming countries to oil-producing countries.
>
> Suggestions include possible coordination of borrowings by indus nations on world financial mkts that will be needed to cover balance-of-payments deficits, new ways of aiding 'poorest' of poor countries, which will be unable to borrow, possible new 'investment fund' to help oil countries place long-term investments, new reciprocal currency 'swap' arrangements among leading central banks and others. Shultz suggestions for industrial countries outlined (M).
>
> Document nyta000020011127d62f07et9

Ideally I wanted to have this headers : section, word count, date, news souce, language and content. Also I may have several if not hundreds of factiva text files, so the parsing has to be run in a loop.

Here is the Python code I've written so far:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample text content
text_content = """
Section 
US Treas Dept on Feb 13 makes public text of speech made by Sec Shultz at...

228 words
15 February 1974
New York Times Abstracts
NYTA
Pg. 1, Col. 1
English
c. 1974 New York Times Company

US Treas Dept on Feb 13 makes public text of speech made by Sec Shultz at closed session of 13-nation energy conf in which he lists ideas and suggestions for dealing with purely financial problems raised for world by huge increase in price of oil. High officials elaborate at background news briefing. Shultz emphasizes that there is no internatl financial arrangement which can offset real effects of oil price changes. Adds that there is no way to print money and use it to 'paper over' problem of high price of oil and its impact on employment, prices and real incomes in rich and poor countries. Shultz's ideas were designed to keep real problem from being made worse by huge new money flows involved, amounting to some $50-billion more in '74 than in '73 from oil-consuming countries to oil-producing countries.

Suggestions include possible coordination of borrowings by indus nations on world financial mkts that will be needed to cover balance-of-payments deficits, new ways of aiding 'poorest' of poor countries, which will be unable to borrow, possible new 'investment fund' to help oil countries place long-term investments, new reciprocal currency 'swap' arrangements among leading central banks and others. Shultz suggestions for industrial countries outlined (M).

Document nyta000020011127d62f07et9
"""

# Define a list of headers
headers = ["Section", "words", "Date", "Source"]

# Create a list to store dictionaries for each section
data_list = []

# Split the text based on the headers
for i in range(len(headers)-1):
    header_start = headers[i]
    header_end = headers[i+1]
    
    section_content = text_content.split(header_start)[1].split(header_end)[0].strip()

    # Create a dictionary for each section
    section_dict = {
        'Header': header_start,
        'Content': section_content
    }

    data_list.append(section_dict)

# Create a pandas DataFrame from the list of dictionaries
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)
```

Comment: How would your expected `data_list` look like? How does it currently look like? Please add both values (as Python code, e.g. output of `print(data_list)`) to the question.

Comment: A txt file usually compose of several news article I want to have a list of title , author,word count, date of publication and the actual content of the article

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that always the info is gonna be in the same lines and with the same structure this could help you:

```
def extract_text_info_fixed(text):
    lines = text.strip().split('\n')

    section = lines[1].strip() if len(lines) > 1 else None
    words = int(lines[3].split()[0]) if len(lines) > 3 else None
    date = lines[4].strip() if len(lines) > 4 else None
    source = lines[5].strip() if len(lines) > 5 else None

    info = {
        "Section": section,
        "Words": words,
        "Date": date,
        "Source": source
    }

    return info
```

For example, if you would apply that for several texts like the one you shared:

```
list_of_texts = ['''
Section 
US Treas Dept on Feb 13 makes public text of speech made by Sec Shultz at...

228 words
15 February 1974
New York Times Abstracts
NYTA
Pg. 1, Col. 1
English
c. 1974 New York Times Company
''',
'''
Section 
Another Section in your texts

99999 words
24 March 2023
Forbes
...
Pg. 1, Col. 1
...
...
''']

data_list = []
for text in list_of_texts:
    result = extract_text_info_fixed(text)
    data_list.append(result)

print(data_list)
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "Section": "US Treas Dept on Feb 13 makes public text of speech made by Sec Shultz at...",
        "Words": 228,
        "Date": "15 February 1974",
        "Source": "New York Times Abstracts"
    },
    {
        "Section": "Another Section in your texts",
        "Words": 99999,
        "Date": "24 March 2023",
        "Source": "Forbes"
    }
]
```